# When this polar curve intersects with the $y$-axis, why is the value of the angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm currently learning area bounded by polar curve on Khan Academey, in one of the exercise, they asked

[image]

[image]

I don't really understand how the value for beta is obtained (or to be more precise, the principle behind how the value was obtained), could someone please expand the answer a little bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gist of it is that in polar coordinates $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ corresponds to the $y$-axis. So, if we want a point on the $y$-axis with the restriction that $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$, then we must have $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Edit: The only systematic way to find the limits of integration in these cases is to solve for the relevant points of intersection (probably not what you wanted to hear/were looking for). But, this will get much easier with practice. It seems that your confusion is stemming from some difficulty or inexperience in thinking about polar coordinates. For example, this case is quite different from the case of Eulidean coordinates where we set two expressions equal and solve. In this case, we are not necessarily trying to solve for $r=0$, but rather identifying an angle that will satisfy the given condition. As far as recommended reading, most first semester calculus texts should discuss this topic. I learned calculus from Stewart's text and have also used it in teaching. You could probably get a used older edition on the cheap and I'd recommend it as a basic calculus text. Aside from that, perhaps try to read about polar coordinates online (wikipedia, online lecture notes, etc) and get some practice thinking in polar as opposed to Euclidean coordinates. I hope this long, somewhat rambling edit is of some help.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your help. Do you mind if I ask a follow up question. I am really confused about how to find the upper and lower bound when solving these type of equations, is there a systematic way to find the upper and lower bound? is there any reading you would recommend?

Comment: @Thor I edited my answer to (attempt to) address your question.

Comment: thank you so much for helping out! your answer will definitely help me go a long way.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it and it's my pleasure. I enjoy having the opportunity to talk with people about math.